# listing the date last created for the current directory

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have never written Python before and have a homework assignment I'm stuck on. 
This is what I need to do. List all files names, size, date created  in the given folder. Filter file size ( you can do =, > or <) it is up to you, or a range. The script should check and validate the folder name, and the size.
The script should loop until find all files greater than the specified size in all the sub-folders.

I've been able to get a list of files and the size but that's it.

This is what I have so far.

```
import os
Path = os.getcwd()
Files = list(os.listdir(Path))

Dict = dict()
for Allfiles in Files: 
    size = os.stat(Allfiles)
    Dict[Allfiles] = size

for item in Dict:
    print("{:30s} {:d} Bytes".format(item,Dict[item].st_size))
```

Comment: use button `{}` to correctly format code.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should to keep in mind following things.

1. You need to process all sub-directories. You can do this with either recursive or iterative approach. I prefer the first one something like this:

```py
def get_all_files(path_to_dir: str) -> dict:
    result = dict()
    for file_name in os.listdir(path_to_dir):
        full_path = os.path.join(path_to_dir, file_name)
        if os.path.isdir(full_path):
            result.update(get_all_files(full_path))
        else:
            result[full_path] = "<info-about-file>"
    return result
```

An iterative looks pretty similar.

2. You need to get information about certain file. `os.stat` returns all necessary data: `st_size` for size, and `st_ctime` for creation time in seconds. You can use `datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp` for converting seconds to readable format.
3. Also the function for size comparison is needed. E.g.

```py
def is_need_to_print_file(size: int, min_size: int=0, max_size: int=-1) -> bool:
    if size < min_size:
        return False
    if max_size != -1 and size > max_size:
        return False
    return True
```

The exact value will be checked if `min_size` is equal to `max_size`.

4. The function `os.path.exists` provides capability for directory path validation.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I think where my problem is more about how to incorporate that code into the code I've written, especially getting the date added to my code. Can you help with that also?

Comment: I think you can do something like this: https://gist.github.com/osanwe/3f69bebfa0b8efd62e85abf350a2fe13